# Converting int/long zero to double

Tags: java, integer, double, type-conversion, long-integer

Considering this code snippet:

```
int i = 0;
double d1 = (double) i;
long l = 0L;
double d2 = (double) l;
```

Running this on my machine prints `0.0` for both conversions. **But can `d1` and `d2` ever be anything but `0.0`?**

As I understand, this is a *widening primitive conversion* to which the [spec says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value.

as well as

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long
>   value to double, may result in loss of precision

As I understand the spec, the above would mean that `int 0` will always become `double 0.0` but `long 0` can be converted to something else (e.g. `1E-20` or something like that). Is my spec interpretation correct?

Comment: How can there be 'loss of precision' of zero? Zero doesn't have any precision to lose. Not a real question.

Comment: As a matter of fact I *have* answered the question, and there is no FUD in it whatsoever. Try not to over-react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full quote is:

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. **In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.**

(Emphasis mine)

This is covering the case where the `int`/`long` value cannot be exactly represented in `float`/`double` (in which case, the nearest representable value is chosen).  Clearly, `0` **can** be represented, so one would not expect a loss of precision.

Comment: This does make sense (even without reading the spec) - but what I am afraid of is - some corner case where JVM *could* do lousy `long->double` conversion and stay perfectly legal, at least as far as the spec goes.

Comment: @mindas: It sounds like the requirement is that the value must be correctly rounded according to the IEEE-754 rules.  I could be wrong, but I can't see how 0 being converted to non-0 could ever be valid, according to the above paragraph.

Comment: +1 All `int` can be represented exactly with a double. (int has 31-bit with a sign, and double has 53-bits with a sign) It's `long` which can have values double can't represent exactly.